# Relative urls for images not working in IE11 or Edge, but do on Chrome/FF

Tags: html, angular, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

I have an Angular 4 front-end application accessing images that are stored on a private S3 bucket. The images are only accessible via an authenticated API call. An example image url would be `https://my-app.com/api/aws/s3/download?key=banner.jpeg`.

When I am on a page such as https://my-app.com/#/ (I am using hashbang for the urls), I can see the image I want with the following img tag: `<img src="/api/aws/s3/download?key=banner.jpeg" />` in Chrome and Firefox.

However, in IE11/Edge, this doesn't work. Using the absolute link instead of the relative one also does not work in IE/Edge.

I do have a base href set up as `./` in my index.html, but this is for my Tomcat server to load my Angular app.

Any thoughts as to why I can't get the image to load?

edit (7/17/17 at 2PM): I see an aborted message in the network tab for IE's dev console for each image. Could this be a SSL issue? Why would Chrome and FF be fine.